# VS2013 overload error (does not happen with gcc)

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, overloading

I am "porting" a multiplatform project code from VS2003 to VS2013.

I hit an error that I cannot understand.

Here's a test code that illustrates it:

```
using namespace std;

class MyString : public string {

public:

    MyString() : string() {};
    MyString(const string   &a_path) : string(a_path) {};
    MyString(const MyString &a_path) : string(a_path) {};

    friend MyString operator+(const MyString& path, const string& s) {
        string str(path);
        return str + s;
    }; 
};

void test() {

    MyString result;
    MyString one;

    result = one + string("aaa"); // error C2666 } }
```

This code can be compiled with VS2003 and several (newer) versions of gcc.
The VS2013 compiler complains with the following error:

```
1>mystring.cpp(22): error C2666: 'operator +' : 3 overloads have similar conversions
1>mystring.cpp(12): could be 'MyString operator +(const MyString &,const std::string &)' [found using argument-dependent lookup] 
1>    [...]\xstring(2411): or  'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> std::operator +<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>(std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &&,std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &&)' 
1>    [...]\xstring(2401): or  'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> std::operator +<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>(std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &&,const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &)' 
1>    [...]\xstring(2391): or  'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> std::operator +<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>(const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &,std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &&)' 
1>    [...]\xstring(2321): or  'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> std::operator +<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>(const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &,const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &)' 
1>    while trying to match the argument list '(MyString, std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>)' 
1>    note: qualification adjustment (const/volatile) may be causing the ambiguity
```

The class in my project is one of basic classes and is used in whole project. So I am looking for a solution that would not affect a lot of code.

Comment: I think that's because `MyString` inherits from `std::string`. The compiler cannot choose between `operator +(const MyString&, const std::string&)` and `operator +(const std::string&, const std::string&)`.

Comment: Don't inherit from std containers. Causes too much hassle. Make your own independent MyString class, with `operator std::string` if necessary.

Comment: I would not do this when writing a new code. In this case I am maintaining an old project where it is done this way.
It is strange why gcc allows it and VS2013 doesn't.
I also do not want to modify several 100s of lines of code to change this class due to change of inheritance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct solution to the problem would be to implement the operator with different arguments.

So the operator declaration should be:

```
MyString operator+(const string& path, const string& s);
```

instead of:

```
MyString operator+(const MyString& path, const string& s);
```

This could be a problem if its implementation would need to access some functionality of class MyString. But that is not true in my case.

Thanks to @Arne Mertz to point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Given the current code you need not (and that means should not) make the operator a friend of your class, because it does not need access to private members:

```
class MyString : public string {

public:

    MyString() : string() {};
    MyString(const string   &a_path) : string(a_path) {};
    MyString(const MyString &a_path) : string(a_path) {};
};

MyString operator+(const MyString& path, const string& s) {
    string str(path);
    return str + s;
};
```

However, while this *might* solve your problem, I should mention that standard library classes like `std::string` are not meant to be derived from, so you should consider other means (e.g. aggregation instead of inheritance) to achieve your goal. That will probably help to solve your problem, too, because the compiler will not consider `MyString` to be a `std::string` and get confused by the overloads available.

In addition, I hope the using directive right before the class' definition is just for the sake of brevity, becuase using directives on namespace scope in a header are very seldom a good thing to do.

**update:** looking more closely at the implementation of the `operator+`, you might want to leave it out completely, since it does what the `operator+` taking two `std::string`'s already does for you.

Comment: Your answer would be acceptable if I would write a new code or the impact of changing the class to use aggregation would not result in changing 100s of lines of code.
Any other suggestion?

Comment: Did you try the free non-friend `operator+`? You would have to change only the header of `MyString` and recompile only the files that include that header.

Comment: The friend keyword does not change anything.

Comment: @Urban: see my update - drop the operator alltogether.